# Is there a way to fill up a (multi)cell's remaining space with dots using pyfpdf2?

Tags: python, django, pdf, pdf-generation, pyfpdf

I'm currently working on a Django project in which the client needs to print reports where remaining spaces are filled up with dots up to the end of the line **dynamically**. I'm using the PyFpdf2 library for PDF reports. The outputs should look like this:
**This is line 1....................**
**This is line 2....................**

I am using basic cells and multicells as:

```
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 12)
pdf.cell(40, 8, 'This is line 1........')
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got the answer I needed. The python string methods `ljust`, `center` and `rjust` are just what I needed!
For instance

```
name = 'John'
print(name.ljust(20, '.')
```

The outputs fills up the remaining spaces with dots like `John..........`